# store and read firebase serviceAccountKey from dotenv (.env) file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, dotenv

I'm using firebase in my project and I want to store its serviceAccountKey.json file in **.env** file like this

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY={
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "abc-123",
  "private_key_id": "123",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n**some string**\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-whatever.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "123",
  "auth_uri": "https://something",
  "token_uri": "https://something",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://something",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://something.com"
}
```

And I'm reading this in my firebase-config file like this

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = process.env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY;

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
});
```

It says

> Failed to parse service account json file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

And then I tried to parse this file like this

```
const serviceAccount = JSON.parse(process.env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY)
```

And now it's saying

> Failed to parse private key: Error: Invalid PEM formatted message.

Please help me storing this json file in .env file